# What's the fastest way to add a few frames at the end of a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

Is there a fast way to do it with ffmpeg or with something else? I mean is there a way to do it without re-encoding the video?

Comment: Do you want to add frames from another video or simple black frame at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFMPEG to concatenate two files, your original file and another file to add to the end. [FFMPEG Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

This will not re-encode, just join the videos.